# This jQuery code is wrong and requires me to keep clearing my cache ... why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to debug a problem and I seemed to have tracked it down but I do not have the technical explanation for why it is happening.

I have a piece of query code that monitors the onclick event on a radio button, and causes a text input(s) to fadein/fadeout according to certain clicks.

What I noticed is even thought his code wasnt changing, I was having to clear my cache to get the code to work properly a lot. I have no clue why but I looked at the code (not written by me):

```
$(function(){     
  $('.radioSelect_2').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "sub_option_1")
    {
      $('#secondary_sub_1').fadeIn("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_2').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_3').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_4').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_5').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_6').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_7').fadeOut("fast");    
    } 
    else
    {
      $('#secondary_sub_1').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_2').fadeIn("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_3').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_4').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_5').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#secondary_sub_6').fadeOut("fast");     
      $('#secondary_sub_7').fadeOut("fast");      
    }   
})
```

And it looks like it is being set up to extend jQuery, so I changed it to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.radioSelect_1').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "option_1")
    {
        $('#sub_1').fadeIn("fast");
        $('#sub_2').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#sub_3').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#sub_4').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#sub_5').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#sub_6').fadeOut("fast");
    } 
   else if ($(this).attr("id") == "option_2")
    {
      $('#sub_1').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#sub_2').fadeIn("fast");
      $('#sub_3').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#sub_4').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#sub_5').fadeOut("fast");
      $('#sub_6').fadeOut("fast");    
    }   
});
```

And it fixes my problem. No more clear cache.etc.
I cannot figure out why, I am hoping guys can.

Comment: i'm not sure your first code sample is syntactically valid. i don't think you can pass an anonymous function to the jquery function... code block #2 is probably what you meant to do, which leaves me at this: what is the question??

Comment: @jbabey You can do that in jQuery now I believe. That said, I don't think you could do that in a lot of previous versions so if you just changed your jQuery version, this might be your problem

Comment: First code block is a shorthand for the second one, maybe the problem is due to the version of jQuery you're using... which version is it btw?

Comment: I feel like you're missing a close `}` on both of these examples.  the `{` never gets closed from `$('.radioSelect_1').click(function(){` <-- seems like a syntax error.  Why it would work on one and not the other is beyond me.  As others have mentioned new-ish versions of jQuery let you do `$(function(){})` as a shortcut to the second example.

Comment: @nzifnab is correct, the first block has syntax errors, specifically, you're missing a });

Comment: i did have some but and paste errors ... but i still do not understand why it fixes the problem. sorry for not being concise enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery's [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - `$(document).ready(handler)`
> - `$().ready(handler)` (this is not recommended)
> - `$(handler)`

The only thing I can see is that you're missing a semi-colon in the first code block, but that is most likely a copypasta error...